# Proving that eigenvalues are real and eigenvectors are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, can I prove that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are real and that all eigenvectors associated with distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal? If so, where do I start to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

**I will provide two different proofs that the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real:**

PROOF 1

Consider $Ax=\lambda x$, and since $A=A^*$, 
$$x^*A^*Ax=(Ax)^*(Ax)=\lambda^2 x^*x \implies \|Ax\|_2^2=\lambda^2 \|x\|_2^2$$

Since $\|Ax\|_2^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\|x\|_2^2 \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

PROOF 2

(1) Consider $Ax=\lambda x$

(2) Then,
$$x^*Ax=\lambda x^*x \tag{1}$$

(3) To proof $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, all we need to show is that in (1) $x^*Ax \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^*x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(4) $x^*x=\|x\|_2^2 \in \mathbb{R}$

(5) $x^*Ax$ is a scalar, so let $\alpha=x^*Ax$ and therefore $\alpha=\alpha^T$.
$$\alpha=(x^*Ax)^T=x^TA^T(x^*)^T=x^TA \bar{x}=\bar{\alpha} \implies \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$

(5) Hence, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

**To proof that the eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal:**

(1) Let $(\lambda , x)$ and $(\mu , y)$ be two distinct eigenpairs of $A$.

(2) Then
$$Ax= \lambda x \quad \Rightarrow \quad y^TAx=\lambda y^Tx \tag{2}$$
$$Ay= \mu x \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^TAy=\mu x^Ty \tag{3}$$

(3) But, $y^Tx=x^Ty$ and since $A=A^T$, 
$$y^TAx=(Ay)^Tx=x^TAy$$

(4) (2)-(3) gives
$$0=(\lambda-\mu)x^Ty$$

(5) Since $\lambda \ne mu$, then $x^Ty=0$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a famous result known as the "spectral theorem". It's a little easier to prove over the complex numbers, but the real symmetric case isn't that much harder. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices .